# Is removing an entity from a hibernate changeset as simple as calling EntityManger.detach()?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

### Background

I have a java/spring system where transactions are managed manually via a custom HandlerInterceptor. That is to say:

- at the begining of every request a transaction is opened (an unfortunate part of the system is that any request might result in a write to the db)
- an EntityManager instance joins the transaction
- the entity manager is used to load entities which are modified. **The EntityManager tracks all changes**
- at the end of every request the EntityManager is flushed and committed

Yes this is not ideal, but I did not create this system and it's simple enough to allow us to work within it's confines - I'm not looking to change it without good reason.

I am not used to commit-all-tracked-entities-on-flush behavior and so have been doing something like:

```
//change entity
if(ovalValidator.isValid(entity))
  em.persist(entity);
```

I need to fix this to work with my new understanding and switching the above to this seems to work:

```
//change entity
if(!ovalValidator.isValid(entity))
  em.detach(entity);
```

### My question

It is my understanding that this just removes the entity from the flush queue even if it IS marked as dirty. Is this correct? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to (don't save changes to that entity)? Is there anything I need to look out for if I'm doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detache removes the entity from the session (changeTracking, lazyloading, ...) it does what you want. You could also implement en interceptor removing the dirty mark of the invalid entities but i think your solution would work as well